# Free open-source software for creating cartoon like characters on Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, graphic-design, vector-graphics

I have technical some technical topics on my blog like refactoring, coding, design patterns, etc.

To express the ideas and explain the concepts, I want to add cartoon characters on my blog. Something like, when I want to explain "how 2 classes are tightly coupled", I will show 2 cartoon characters hugging each other.

Here is the sample concept that I want to make for my blog: https://zhart.us/refactoring-illustrations/

I am looking for a open-source software that can help me to create cartoon like characters.

I want the:

- ability to move their body parts
- Animation not required. Just static images.
- Change body proportions and change body parts

Some examples of characters that I am looking for:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]